# MySQL Max with wrong fields

Tags: mysql, sql, max

When executing below query

```
SELECT `game_turns`.`in_darts`, `game_turns`.`date`, MAX(game_turns.score) AS max_score
FROM `game_turns`
JOIN `games` ON `games`.`id` = `game_turns`.`game_id` AND `games`.`training` = 1
WHERE `game_turns`.`uid` = 2
AND `game_turns`.`out` = 1
AND `game_turns`.`in_darts` = 3
ORDER BY `game_turns`.`score` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

I get the max score for that user id (uid) and out in 3 darts, but the rest (date) is wrong.

Fields are

```
Score   Uid     GameID      Score    out    in_darts    date
121     2       4           8        1      3           2015-07-21 13:52:12
8465    2       142         100      1      3           2015-09-05 19:46:29
```

It returns the score 100 from row ID 8465 but the rest is from row ID 121

I have googled it and came on some Stackoverflow results saying that I should use ORDER BY and LIMIT 1, but looks like it aint working for me.

Order by Date also didn't do the trick.

Comment: using aggregate function and selecting multiple columns does not grantee of returning proper values other than the column used in aggregate. Also you can create a fiddle with some sample data and expected result into the question so that others can try out.

Comment: How does a table have 2 columns with the label `Score`? Exactly what is the "expected result" from that sample of data (the second row?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `order by` and `limit` should do what you want:

```
SELECT gt.`in_darts`, gt.`date`, gt.score
FROM `game_turns` gt JOIN
     `games` g
     ON g.`id` = gt.`game_id` AND g.`training` = 1
WHERE gt.`uid` = 2 AND gt.`out` = 1 AND gt.`in_darts` = 3
ORDER BY gt.`score` DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

There is no need for aggregation.

Comment: Thanks, sometimes the solution is really simple :) Works like a charm! Edit : Mhhhh can't upvote :(

Answer (score 0):

If seeking a solution that would work for multiple UID's then aggregation becomes useful - via a subquery.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f0c33/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`Score_A` int, `Uid` int, `GameID` int, `Score_B` int, `out` int, `in_darts` int, `date` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`Score_A`, `Uid`, `GameID`, `Score_B`, `out`, `in_darts`, `date`)
VALUES
    (121, 2, 4, 8, 1, 3, '2015-07-21 13:52:12'),
    (8465, 2, 142, 100, 1, 3, '2015-09-05 19:46:29')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
      t.*
FROM table1 t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Uid, max(Score_B) as Score_B
  FROM table1
  GROUP BY uid
  ) msb ON t.Uid = msb.Uid and t.Score_B = msb.Score_B
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f0c33/1/0)**:

```
| Score_A | Uid | GameID | Score_B | out | in_darts |                        date |
|---------|-----|--------|---------|-----|----------|-----------------------------|
|    8465 |   2 |    142 |     100 |   1 |        3 | September, 05 2015 19:46:29 |
```